# Hibernate Primary Key annotation returns null value

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate

i am following http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-tutorial-using-annotation/

for learning primary key annotation.

I have two classes

```
@Id
@Column
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String password;
private String profession;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="user" , cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Profile profile;
```

and my profile class

```
@Id
@Column
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id; //profileId
private int userId;
private String specialization;
private String hospital;
private String clinicAddress;
private String clinicTime;
private String about;


@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private User user;
```

There are entries in both tables, but i am getting `null` value for profile. Can any one tell me whats the problem in my code. My tables are

profile table is :

```
CREATE TABLE `profile` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`userId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`specialization` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`hospital` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`clinicAddress` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`clinicTime` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
`about` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `fk` (`userId`),
KEY `pfk` (`userId`),
CONSTRAINT `pfk` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE   NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

and user table is

```
CREATE TABLE user (
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
firstName varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
lastName varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
email varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
password varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
profession varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

EDIT : When i use

```
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
private User user;
```

and remove the `userId` field from Profile class, It works find and i get the profile object too.

Now when i add the `userId` field in Profile class, i get

```
Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.analyst.future.domain.Profile column: userId (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

UserProfileForm :

```
 UserProfileForm {

private int userId;
private String specialization;
private String hospital;
private String clinicAddress;
private String clinicTime;
private String about;
```

Controller :

```
public String registerNewUser(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute ("form") SignupForm form){
    User user = new User();
    try {
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(user, form);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {    
        logger.error("ERROR : unable to copy values from form to user object");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Integer userId = userService.addUser(user);
    UserProfileForm profileForm = new UserProfileForm();
    profileForm.setUserId(userId);
    profileService.addProfile(profileForm);

    mailService.sendAccountCreatingNotification(user);

    return REDIRECT_CONFIRMATION_VIEW;
}
```

In profileService :

```
public Profile addProfile(UserProfileForm form) {
    Profile profile = new Profile();
    try {
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(profile, form);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    return profileDAO.addProfile(profile);
}
```

and in ProfileDAOImpl

```
public Profile addProfile(Profile profile) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.persist(profile);       
    return profile;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping says that the ID of profile is also a join column (i.e. a foreign key referencing the user ID). That's what `@PrimiryKeyJoinColumn` means.

But your table definition shows that you have a userId column in profile to reference the profile's user ID.  So you should in fact use `@JoinColumn(name = "userId")`.

Make up your mind, and choose what you actually want to do.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did that and in that case it worked fine too, but the issue was that i had to remove the userId variable from Profile class. And in that case i am then not able to add userId in profile table for adding new  user.

Comment: Define "I'm not able". What do you do, whet do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Edit your question.

Comment: Nized i have updated the question for the error i get when i use the solution you have suggested.

Comment: You should not add userId. You already have a OneToOne with User. Adding a userId would be redundant.

Comment: Yes you are right, but when i remove this field from the Profile class, and add a new profile, then value inside the user id is null, which should be the id of new user.

Comment: Once again, without seeing your code, I can't explain what is wrong and how to fix it. Show how you create a profile and associate it with a user.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i have added the whole code now. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You're never setting the user in your profile object. So obviously, it's null. `BeanUtils.copyProperties(profile, form)`won't magically get the user with the given user ID from the hibernate session and set the user in the profile object.

Answer (score 1):

In Profile object you have following lines:

```
@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private User user;
```

Change these to:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
private User user;
```

PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation is wrongly used here. Your database table does not suggest that user_id is primary key join column.

Comment: How can i make my user_id a primary key join column then? as i get some issues when use the solution you have suggested.